# How to get the last two registration on xml with jinja2

Tags: django, jinja2, xmltodict

I receive a webservice in XML, I change it to dict with xmltodict. Then in the submit.html I use jinja2 to read the dict and get the values. The problem is I get a lot of entries with:

```
<institution code="A15">
      <transition type="credit" code="N" href="https://.../739"></transition>
      <transition type="credit" code="N" href="https://.../741"></transition>
      <transition type="credit" code="N" href="https://.../759"></transition >
```

I want to read the last 2 entries and only the "important_id" part. Like:
741
759

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loop.revindex` in [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/)

```
{% for key, value in your_dict.iteritems() %}
  {% if loop.revindex <= 2 %}
    {# use key and value here #}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will only use the last two key-value pairs in your dict.

Comment: between .iteritems and (), there's the red light error saying "expected %}.